# Is configuration of AMDGPU-pro on my laptop correct?

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics

I installed amdgpu-pro on ubuntu 16.04. After reboot the screen resolution was low and unity not start. But I can open applications by right clicking and opening terminal. The speed was low too.
The following is the output of gpu-manager.

> last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
>
> new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
>
> can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
>
> can't access /run/u-d-c-fglrx-was-loaded file
>
> Looking for fglrx modules in /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/updates/dkms
>
> Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/updates/dkms
>
> Is nvidia loaded? no
>
> Was nvidia unloaded? no
>
> Is nvidia blacklisted? no
>
> Is fglrx loaded? no
>
> Was fglrx unloaded? no
>
> Is fglrx blacklisted? yes
>
> Is intel loaded? no
>
> Is radeon loaded? no
>
> Is radeon blacklisted? yes
>
> Is amdgpu loaded? no
>
> Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
>
> Is nouveau loaded? no
>
> Is nouveau blacklisted? no
>
> Is fglrx kernel module available? no
>
> Is nvidia kernel module available? no
>
> Vendor/Device Id: 1002:7145
>
> BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
>
> Is boot vga? yes
>
> Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/driver
>
> The device is not bound to any driver. Skipping...
>
> Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
>
> Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
>
> Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
>
> Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
>
> Does it require offloading? no
>
> last cards number = 0
>
> Has amd? no
>
> Has intel? no
>
> Has nvidia? no
>
> How many cards? 0
>
> Has the system changed? No
>
> main_arch_path x86_64-linux-gnu, other_arch_path i386-linux-gnu
>
> Current alternative: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
>
> Current core alternative: (null)
>
> Current egl alternative: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/ld.so.conf
>
> Is nvidia enabled? no
>
> Is nvidia egl enabled? no
>
> Is fglrx enabled? no
>
> Is mesa enabled? yes
>
> Is mesa egl enabled? yes
>
> Is pxpress enabled? no
>
> Is prime enabled? no
>
> Is prime egl enabled? no
>
> Is nvidia available? no
>
> Is nvidia egl available? no
>
> Is fglrx available? no
>
> Is fglrx-core available? no
>
> Is mesa available? yes
>
> Is mesa egl available? yes
>
> Is pxpress available? no
>
> Is prime available? no
>
> Is prime egl available? no

Is the above configuration is correct for amdgpu-pro work properly?

graphics card (before installing amdgpu-pro):

```
Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RV515/M54 [Mobility Radeon X1400]
bus-ID: 01:00.0
chip-ID: 1002:7145
Display Server: X.Org 1.18.3
drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
Resolution: 1280x800@60.04hz
GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV515
GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 11.2.0 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you pasted seems to suggest amdgpu is not loaded, and you have no DRI available. It seems also that previously you were using the radeon driver, not amdgpu. It seems you need to uninstall amdgpu-pro, as your graphics chip is not supported by it, being too old, and you must use the radeon drivers instead.

The amdgpu-pro installation appears to have blacklisted the radeon driver, which is required for your card.